# XCopy won't copy from path of the batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy, intune

I have an intune package which runs a batch script as follows.

```
SET INST=%~dp0

xcopy %INST%\Folder1\* "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Folder2" /s /i
```

Goal is to copy files from Folder1 to Folder2. The Batch script and folder 1 are in the same main folder. No files are being copied so I'm confused.

Thanks,

Comment: OK, in that case, is the value of `INST` exactly what you expect it to be? Also, the correct filesystem permissions for a user should prevent writing in the "C:\Program Files (x86)" directory. Please see [How-to: Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) for the normal locations that you might use, such as `APPDATA` or `LOCALAPPDATA`.

Comment: Your first line should read as `SET "INST=%~dp0"`, and the second should be `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%INST%Folder1" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Test\Folder2\" /S`. You should note that this code will only work if your end user has permissions for the destination directory.

Comment: @Mofi , I just tried your implementation and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The two command lines could be replaced by the single command line:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~dp0Folder1" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Test\Folder2\" /S
```

The batch file with this command line needs to be **run as administrator** because of the directory referenced with `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` is usually write-protected for standard users.

The help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window explains on last help page that a file name (or any other argument string like a password) containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` (or literally to interpret `<>|` as in a password) must be enclosed in `"` to be interpreted as **one** argument string on which all characters are interpreted literally with the exception of `%` and `!` if delayed expansion is enabled on parsing the command line in the batch file. It is advisable to enclose file/folder argument strings always in double quotes if there is not guaranteed that `"` are not needed as for `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe`.

The [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) **XCOPY** is specified with fully qualified file name. That improves efficiency as the Windows Command Processor does not need to search in file system for an executable/script with file name `xcopy` in current directory and in the directories listed separated with semicolons in value of local environment variable `PATH` with a file extension listed in value of local environment variable `PATHEXT`. The usage of the fully qualified file name makes this command line also fail safe because of no `xcopy.cmd` in current directory or a corrupted `PATH` not containing anymore `%SystemRoot%\System32` can cause anymore a different execution of this command line than the expected one.

There is no backslash between `%~dp0` and `Folder1` in source argument string because of `%~dp0` always expands to full path of the directory containing the batch file ending with `\`. So the resulting argument string of `%~dp0Folder1` is 100% valid which must not be modified in any way by the Windows [file I/O functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) before passing the directory argument string to the file system.

There can be appended to source argument string `\*`, i.e. use `"%~dp0Folder1\*"` as first argument string for **XCOPY**, but copying all files in the specified source directory, and with option `/S` also all files in non-empty directories, is the default.

The destination argument string ends with a backslash. That makes it 100% clear for **XCOPY** that the destination is a directory. That backslash at end makes it unnecessary to use option `/I`. **XCOPY** creates always the entire directory tree to the destination directory. The destination is definitely a directory with destination argument string ending with a backslash.

The usage of **XCOPY** is deprecated since Windows Vista and Windows Server 2003 on which **ROBOCOPY** is installed by default in the Windows system directory. [ROBOCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) is a more robust and more powerful file/directory copying/moving program. Run in a command prompt window `robocopy /?` for output of its usage help or read the Microsoft documentation for [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

The same directory copying task can be done with **ROBOCOPY** with:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%~dp0Folder1" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Test\Folder2" /S /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:2 /W:3 >nul
```

**ROBOCOPY** creates also the entire destination directory tree if that is necessary.

It is important to mention that `robocopy.exe` uses a special argument string parsing like `reg.exe`. A `\` left to one more `\` or a `"` is interpreted as escape character for the following backslash or double quote character. For that reason no argument string of **ROBOCOPY** enclosed in `"` should end with a single backslash as that would be interpreted as escape for the double quote and so everything up to next `"` is interpreted as one argument string although a directory path cannot contain the character `"` at all.

Valid **ROBOCOPY** command lines are regarding to source and destination:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%~dp0Folder1" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Test\Folder2" /S
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%~dp0Folder1\\" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Test\Folder2\\" /S
```

Invalid **ROBOCOPY** command lines are regarding to source and destination:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe %~dp0Folder1 %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Test\Folder2 /S
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%~dp0Folder1\" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Test\Folder2\" /S
```

The first line is invalid as `%~dp0` could expand to a string containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` expands by default to a string containing a space and both round brackets and therefore source and destination path must be enclosed in double quotes.

If the root directory of a drive is the source or destination on which it is necessary that the directory path ends with a backslash, it is best not enclosing the root directory path like `C:\` or `D:\` in double quotes.